# vsCode extension how to create window/dialogue at statubar

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am trying to create a vs code extensions, I need to show a small window at statusbar when my extension icon is clicked, with some custom text and buttons in that window. For now I can only show tooltip. How to show window there.

[image: reference image]